# Why the "specified cast not available" error?

Tags: c#, database

Why do I get this error? What does it mean?

The the first if statement executes, but then the program stops and the error comes in.

The value that comes with rowsource is a decimal
The `numericScale < NumericPrecision` statement should work.

```
if (((Type)rowSource["DataType"]).FullName == "System.Decimal")
{
    // The default Decimal in SQL is decimal(18,0). Access does not show the number of decimals.
    string dataType;
    short numericScale;

    if ((short)rowSource["NumericScale"] < (short)rowSource["NumericPrecision"])
    {
        // Access has rowSource["NumericScale"] = 255
        if ((short)rowSource["NumericPrecision"] > 15)
        {
            // Use money as best guess
            dataType = "money";
            numericScale = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            dataType = "decimal";
            numericScale = (short)rowSource["NumericPrecision"];
            numericScale = Convert.ToInt16(numericScale/2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dataType = "decimal";
        numericScale = (short)rowSource["NumericScale"];
    }

    sb.Append(
        objDbTarget.SqlColumnDefinition(
            objDbTarget.ColumnNameEnclosed(colName),
            dataType,
            (int)rowSource["ColumnSize"],
            (short)rowSource["NumericPrecision"],
            numericScale,
            (bool)rowSource["AllowDbNull"]
        )
    ).Append(comma);
}
```

i found out that the code gives the error when i use this piece of code somewhere.

```
//if (objDbTarget.DbType != dbTypeEnum.Sqlite)
            //{
            //    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SchemaTarget))
            //    {
            //        SchemaTarget = "dbo";
            //    }
            //}
```

but when i don't use it the code gives me this error.

> - $exception  {"Query = \r\n\r\nCREATE SCHEMA [] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]\r\nTimeout seconds = 30\r\nConnection string = Data Source=UTCD108938; Connect Timeout=30; Integrated Security=SSPI\r\n_keepConnectionOpen = False, _beginTransaction = False"}

Comment: What is type of rowSource["NumericScale"]? are you sure it is short??

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: The casting and data access to rowSource["NumericScale"] and others is done multiple times - which is inefficient and error prone. Better declare a variable, then set it to rowsource[...] and use it later.

Comment: Please share some sample data and the tentative types from `rowSource`

Comment: It looks like that based on your comment that the database columns for these 2 fields are defined as type decimal. Thus you should not cast it to short but to decimal.